# Clojure Function Naming Conventions

Tags: clojure

### Context

Suppose I have protocols ICursor, IFoo, IBar then I can have a function named:

```
(defn IFoo->IBar [foo] ... )
```

Now, suppose I have a function which takes two arguments

```
x: ICursor
y: IFoo
```

and output an object of type IBar.

Now, is there any standard way to denote this in a function name? For example, none of the following work:

```
(defn ICursor,IFoo->IBar [x y] ...)
```

because "," is treated as space

```
(defn (ICursor, IFoo)->IBar [x y] ... )
```

because () is treated as function application.

```
(defn [ICursor, IFoo]->IBar [x y] ... )
```

because [] is treated as vector.

### Question

Is there a standard way to encode protocol types of arguments in the function name?

Thanks!

Comment: `*+!-_?` are valid characters in symbols.  You could use `ICursor+IFoo->IBar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is any such recommended way and it seems like sort of type annotations. There is one such project around giving type annotations to clojure code at this [link](https://github.com/frenchy64/typed-clojure).

You can use something like : `(defn ICursor->IFoo->IBar [x y] ...)`  which denotes that the function takes ICursor and IFoo as params and return IBar, so basically last type is return type and before that everything is parameter type but I am not sure if that can be a long term or idiomatic solution because then where is the method actual name :) which is important then type annotation.